# What influences the default currency of a windows desktop WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, globalization

My local development machine has its region set as United Kingdom. When I do this:

```
 int total = 34;
 string.Format("{0:C}", total ?? 0);
```

I get the result "£34.00" as I'd expect. I have several unit tests that check similar string formatting occurs.

The build server failed on these tests because the result came back as "$34.00" instead. When I check its region was set as United States so I changed it. I double checked the currency tab did indeed default to "£". And I rebooted the server just to be sure.

It's still formatting these numbers as "$34.00". I changed the tests to ignore the first character to get the build through. But it begs the question: if resetting the Windows region doesn't change this behaviour, what does?

Comment: Does the server have United Kingdom language installed ?

Comment: @Versatile yep.